# How to use [Created By] in a column?

Tags: calculated-column

SP 2007, calendar list. Want to add a column that gets its default value from "Created By" but then allows that to be edited. This is what I tried:

1. Create column
2. Give it a name
3. Leave type set to **Single line of text**
4. Change **Default value** to **Calculated Value**
5. Enter **=[Created By]**
6. Click **OK**

SP throws this error:

> One or more column references are not allowed, because the columns are defined as a data type that is not supported in formulas.

Is there another way to do what I need?

Comment: @Steve: Click the tick next to the best answer to give your thanks. Cheers!

Answer (score 9):

Try to insert

```
=[Me]
```

Also look at my answer to a similar post here:

[Calculated value for Title field?](/questions/1118/calculated-value-for-title-field)

Comment: That did it! Thanks much. I feel like such a SP newbie.

Comment: When someone edits the properties the column will then be updated with that current user, which may not be the person who created it.

Comment: @Stein I went ahead and converted your answer to a comment. With a bit more  reputation, you will be able to [post comments everywhere](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/privileges/comment).

Comment: @Stein - this is for the Default Value - not a calculated column, so only applies when the record is first created.

Answer (score 2):

This will do the trick:

```
=[Me]
```

[“Today”, “Me” and SharePoint](http://blog.pathtosharepoint.com/2008/09/15/today-me-and-sharepoint/)

Comment: I wish it would display the person's full name rather than the login, but it's good enough for what I need.

Answer (score 1):

I created a column - "Creator" - Person/Group
In the sharepoint designer, I made a "When new item is created" workflow to update the "Creator" as "Created By".

Answer (score 0):

I would create a SharePoint Designer workflow to populate the "editable created by" field with the "created by" field whenever an item is created and skip calculated columns altogether.

Answer (score -2):

Me will display the value for the current user only. If the item was not created by "Current User" even then this column will be displaying Current User's name which is incorrect in this scenario.
You cannot use "Created By" column as it is not supported by SharePoint calculated field mechanism.

Comment: well the person that creates the item should be current user, right? "Me" will display as domain\account. The user can then choose to accept his own login that is suggested as default, or type in another value.

Comment: Easy to see why you would think this, Namwar, but calculated columns are calculated on item save, and then stored as text (to prevent excessive load on the server). Therefore, a "Me" column will always contain the name of the user who last edited it. Yes, it's a bug rather than a feature, but it's a convenient one.

Answer (score -2):

Using =[Me] generates an error in SP 2010 anyway.

Just change the name of the createdby column to whatever: Requestor - Signee whatever you need that works.

Comment: -1 The OP mentions that the column should be editable. Also, I'm not sure why you think `=[Me]` in a default value causes an error, perhaps you have an unrelated issue?